# Multimonitor - Open the application window in the monitor where mouse cursor is located

Tags: delphi, position, center, monitor

I have a Delphi 7 main form with an "open" button, that opens another form, just like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    Application.CreateForm(TfrmPswd, frmPswd);
    Application.NormalizeTopMosts;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    frmPswd.ShowModal;
  finally
    frmPswd.Release;
    frmPswd := nil;
  end;
end;
```

On the frmPswd OnCreate event I am trying to centralize it, depending on monitor where mouse cursor is located, like this:

```
procedure TfrmPswd.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Monitor: TMonitor;
begin
  Monitor := Screen.MonitorFromPoint(Mouse.CursorPos);
  frmPswd.Top := Round((Monitor.Height - frmPswd.Height) / 2);
  frmPswd.Left := Round((Monitor.Width - frmPswd.Width) / 2);
end;
```

When the main form is located in the same monitor as the mouse cursor, frmPswd form opens like expected, in the center of that monitor. But when the main form is in a monitor different from mouse, frmPswd appears in a strange position I can't understand why.

**EDIT:**

Here are the results as asked by Remy Lebeau, even with the new code:

```
Monitor := Screen.MonitorFromPoint(Mouse.CursorPos);
Self.Left := Monitor.Left + ((Monitor.Width - Self.Width) div 2);
Self.Top := Monitor.Top + ((Monitor.Height - Self.Height) div 2);

Monitor 0
Top: 0
Left: 0
Width: 1440
Height: 900

Monitor 1
Top: -180
Left: -1920
Width: 1920
Height: 1080

frmPswd.Width = 200
frmPswd.Height = 200

Main form in Monitor 0 and Mouse cursor in Monitor 0
frmPswd.Top = 350
frmPswd.Left = 620

Main form in Monitor 1 and Mouse cursor in Monitor 1
frmPswd.Top = 260
frmPswd.Left = -1060

Main form in Monitor 0 and Mouse cursor in Monitor 1
frmPswd.Top = 440
frmPswd.Left = 860

Main form in Monitor 1 and Mouse cursor in Monitor 0
frmPswd.Top = 170
frmPswd.Left = -1300
```

Comment: The different monitor is probably not at (0, 0), add its offset. So form.left=monitor.left+.....

Comment: BTW, it is not a good idea to use the mouse as a determining factor for form placement. One can launch your program using the keyboard from its shortcut on the main monitor and then wonder where has the logon form gone.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, thank you for answering. You are right, second monitor top left is not (0, 0). but when doing frmPswd.Left := Monitor.Left + Round((Monitor.Width - frmPswd.Width) / 2) I got same problem :(

Comment: It is the first time I am trying to work with more than one monitor. What do you think is a better approach for this?

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger to examine the values you're getting to figure out why it's not working as expected?

Comment: Use some kind of persistence for main form's placement, launch logon form on the same monitor. If there's no persistence data, launch them on the main monitor.

Comment: @KenWhite, I did this, but I got strange values I can't yet understand...

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, please, do you know how can I check main monitor? Main monitor is always active? Thanks!

Comment: *I got strange values*? They're numbers that indicate where the mouse pointer is located, what the monitor width and height are, and where your form is located.

Comment: What are the *actual values* you are seeing?

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem with a simple program with D7. To start from somewhere, you need to determine if those are the values that you set to your form, or if the form ignores the values that you set and replaces itself.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, maybe my virtual screen is different from yours? Maybe there are more different kinds of virtual screens? I do not know, so I prefer not to take the risk and used only the primary monitor with a persistence data, as you suggested before. Thank you!

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't understand multi monitor well enough to formulate your desired behaviour. It's too early for you to write your code.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using `Application.CreateForm()` like this.  Use `TfrmPswd.Create()` instead.  And use `Free()` instead of `Release()`.

Get rid of `Application.NormalizeTopMosts()` and `Application.ProcessMessages()` calls, they don't belong in this code at all.

In your `OnCreate` event, use `Self` instead of the global `frmPswd` variable.

And you need to add the `Monitor.Left` and `Monitor.Top` offsets to your new coordinates, to account for monitors that do no start at offset 0,0 of the [Virtual Screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145136.aspx).

Try something more like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  frm: TfrmPswd;
begin
  frm := TfrmPswd(nil);
  try
    frm.ShowModal;
  finally
    frm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure TfrmPswd.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Monitor: TMonitor;
begin
  Monitor := Screen.MonitorFromPoint(Mouse.CursorPos);
  Self.Left := Monitor.Left + ((Monitor.Width - Self.Width) div 2);
  Self.Top := Monitor.Top + ((Monitor.Height - Self.Height) div 2);
end;
```

Comment: thank you! I will make tests! Btw, I edited the question with the position results of my tests...

Comment: Unfortunatelly I have the same results with Self instead of frmPswd :( Btw, the results I included in the question already uses Monitor.Left + ... and Monitor.Top + ... Please, any other idea?

Comment: `Mouse.CursorPos` uses the Win32  `GetCursorPos()` function, which is affected by DPI and LargeAddress issues. Try using the Win32 `GetCursorInfo()` or `GetPhysicalCursorPos()` functions instead.

Comment: Ok, let me try. Thanks!

Comment: Dear Remy Lebeau, I gived up of this solution. GetCursorInfo didn't solve the problem. So I think maybe there are different "kinds" of virtual screens, different positions, I don't know... So I prefered not to take the risk and used only the primary monitor with a persistence data.

Comment: It is the second time you tell me not to use Application.CreateForm(), but I coundn't make it work correctly with your code above, even with "frm := TfrmPswd.Create(nil);". When I click in the Open button, nothing happens in the first time, only when I click again. Do you know what is going on? Thank you!

Comment: Why not call MonitorFromWindow and launch the new window on that monitor ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145064(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: There is only one virtual screen. Did you try `GetPhysicalCursorPos()`?

Comment: I researched about GetPhysicalCursorPos, but didn't find a simple example for me to understand it. But I think MonitorFromPoint is not the problem, because it always return the correct monitor. I checked it using Monitor.MonitorNum.

Comment: @Remko, thanks for the tip. I didn't try MonitorFromWindow yet. I will research about it...

Comment: @Paruba - If you decide to use the monitor that the calling form is on, you can set the logon form's position to poScreenCenter and its default monitor to dmActiveForm and not write a single line of code.

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved with the help of Microsoft powertoys too.
Were you will be given with an option to use active focus or mouse pointer under fancy zones.

Comment: That does not answer the original question. The question is how to implement that behaviour in a Delph program. While MS PowerToys are nice, they do not help here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).